# Limit php if statement to evaluate last write

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to get a couple of php if statements to only run when the last fwrite has run. And I only want to output one $key using $output.  Here's my code snippet:

```
$cnt = 1;
fwrite($fh, $phptag);
$cnt = 2;
// The last fwrite that I want checked
fwrite($fh, $key);
// Check if write has been successful
if ($fwrite !== false && $cnt == 2) {
  $output = json_encode(array( // create JSON data
    'type'=>'success', 
    'text' => 'Congratulations !  The salt key has been successfully created.'
  ));
  exit($output); // exit script outputting json data
}
// Check if write has been unsuccessful
if ($fwrite === false && $cnt == 2) {
  $output = json_encode(array( // create JSON data
   'type'=>'error', 
    'text' => 'There has been an error in creating the salt key.'
  ));
  exit($output); // exit script outputting json data
}
```

I tried using $cnt to control when to run, but the $output is never sent back to the ajax done statement - just getting undefined.  What did I do wrong?

UPDATED CODE:

```
fwrite($fh, $phptag);
// The last fwrite that I want checked
fwrite($fh, $key);
// Check if write has been successful
if (fwrite($fh, $key)) { // Check if write has been successful
  $output = json_encode(array( // create JSON data
    'type'=>'success', 
    'text' => 'Congratulations !  The salt key has been successfully created.'
  ));
}
else {  // Check if write has been unsuccessful
  $output = json_encode(array( // create JSON data
    'type'=>'error', 
    'text' => 'There has been an error in creating the salt key.'
  ));
}
exit($output); // exit script outputting json data
fclose($fh);
```

UPDATE #2:

```
fwrite($fh, $phptag);
//fwrite($fh, $key);
// Check if write has been successful
if (fwrite($fh, $key)) { // Check if write has been successful
  $output = json_encode(array( // create JSON data
    'type'=>'success', 
    'text' => 'Congratulations !  The salt key has been successfully created.'
  ));
}
else {  // Check if write has been unsuccessful
  $output = json_encode(array( // create JSON data
    'type'=>'error', 
    'text' => 'There has been an error in creating the salt key.'
  ));
}
exit($output); // exit script outputting son data
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Where are you setting `$fwrite`?

Comment: fwrite just uses fopen function to write to a file - that's no problem.

Answer (score 2):

`fwrite` returns the number of bytes written to the file, or `FALSE` if there was an error. So you can check for this.

```
if (fwrite($fh, $key)) {
    $output = json_encode(array( // create JSON data
        'type'=>'success', 
        'text' => 'Congratulations !  The salt key has been successfully created.'
      ));
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array( // create JSON data
        'type'=>'error', 
        'text' => 'There has been an error in creating the salt key.'
    ));
}
exit($output);
```

Comment: Hmmmm... Ok so the original problem I was trying to solve was that the output from fwrite was happening twice - that's what I'm trying to avoid.  Won't your code run twice w/ the two fwrite statements?

Comment: Where do you see two `fwrite` statements?

Comment: Oh, ok, I see you are targeting $key - that makes sense, but it still is giving undefined - I'll post updated code above, just to be sure.

Comment: All this tells you is that there wasn't an error writing to the file, such as a permission failure (but this would normally be detected when opening the file). What is giving undefined?

Comment: The 'text' is being written by the ajax done or fail functions to the html (that's where the undefined is showing up - Note: it was writing out the text before I tried making this adjustment, so I'm pretty sure the ajax is correct.

Comment: Look at the raw response in the Network tab of developer tools to see everything that's being returned by AJAX. There may be something else being printed that's interfering with the JSON parse.

Comment: Ok, I removed an echo that was in front of the output.  They are showing up now, but I'm back to two successful statements - I tried changed else to if (fwrite($fh, $key) == false), but still getting two.

Comment: I'm wondering if fwrite runs whenever you mention it?, i.e. actually writes to the file when used in if-statement, as I'm also getting two $key written out

Comment: A function call runs whenever you execute it. If you replace `else` with `if (fwrite($fh, $key) == false)`, it has to execute it again so it can test the new result.

Comment: That's why you should only mention it once, and use `else`.

Comment: Well, I set it back to your if/else code shown above, but it's still writing out two $key And I even tried removing the fwrite above the if statements, but still getting two.

Comment: Then those writes must be happening somewhere else.

Comment: You removed the line `fwrite($fh, $key)` that's before the `if` statement, right?

Comment: Yes, I removed the fwrite line & it has to be coming from this script, as this is the only script where these things are being written from.

Comment: Please update your question and add your current code. Don't delete the original code, that's needed for context of the answer.

Comment: There's no way that can write the key twice. It should write the phptag once and the key once.

Comment: Well, it's doing it - I'd post an image to prove it if I could ;)

Comment: There must be something else going on, like you're calling the code twice. There's no magic here, statements are executed in order, they don't execute twice by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using exit instead of return? This is your problem I thought

You can avoid the unsuccessfull check cause if write was unsuccessfull you will reach your error output always .

Comment: `return` can only be used in a function.

Comment: @Barmar Actually it [can be](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) used in the global scope.